# How to add a command to the history when it is run inside of a bash script?

Tags: bash

I have a long command that I run with minor modifications routinely. To make the modifications easier, I put the command into a .sh file and edit with my favorite editor, then execute the .sh file.

I'd like the commands I run from inside that file to be added to the bash history. How can this be accomplished?

Comment: Have you considered defining a parameterized function to run instead?

Comment: How do you execute the .sh file?  Do you source it or run it as a chile process?

Comment: @chepner, the content of the command changes quite dramatically, too much so handle easily with parameters.

Comment: @cdarke, I'm sourcing it, would running as a child process be helpful?

Answer (score 2):

you can add to `~/.bash_history` inside your script:

```
cmd="date +'%F %H:%M' "
eval "$cmd"
echo "$cmd # run by $0" >> ~/.bash_history
```

in you current shell to get the updates as they happen

```
history -a # add anything you've done recently to the history file
myScript.bash # run your code
history -r # reload history file
```